# Please help me out with the sql query which I'm trying to write

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I want to delete IITESE from all the compartmentID whose parent is CTSC. but i got this error saying

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My query is

```
delete  from [KRISADMIN].[CompartmentACL] where CompartmentID = (select CompartmentID from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] where Name = 'CTSC') and 
TrusteeID = (select RoleID from [KRISADMIN].[Role] where Name = 'IITSE') and TrusteeType = 2
```

Please excuse my query if it is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use = when the subquery returns only 1 value.

When subquery returns more than 1 value, you will have to use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

Using `IN`:

```
delete  from [KRISADMIN].[CompartmentACL] 
where CompartmentID IN (select CompartmentID 
                        from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] 
                        where Name = 'CTSC') 
and TrusteeID IN (select RoleID 
                  from [KRISADMIN].[Role] 
                  where Name = 'IITSE') 
and TrusteeType = 2
```

Read more [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

**EDIT:**

You need to replace `=` with `IN`:

```
delete from [KRISADMIN].[CompartmentACL] 
where CompartmentID IN (select CompartmentID 
                        from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] 
                        where Name in (Select Name 
                                       from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] 
                                       where ParentID IN (Select ParentID 
                                                         from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] 
                                                         where Name = 'CTSC') )) 
and TrusteeID IN (select RoleID 
                  from [KRISADMIN].[Role] 
                  where Name = 'IITSE') 
and TrusteeType = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the knowledge and i edited by query but face another problem. It only deletes away from one CompartmentID instead of all..my new query is as below

Comment: "delete  from [KRISADMIN].[CompartmentACL] where CompartmentID IN (select CompartmentID from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] where Name in (Select Name from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] where ParentID =(Select ParentID from [KRISADMIN].[Compartment] where Name = 'CTSC') )) and 
TrusteeID = (select RoleID from [KRISADMIN].[Role] where Name = 'IITSE') and TrusteeType = 2
"

Comment: Thanks for the help. You taught me something new today. But I still dont get the result i want. Maybe its because my original query is not good enough. Anyway, Thanks for the help.have a nice day.:)